# Can spin orientation change with the excitement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, identical-particles

Let's say we have a 1 dimensional square well system with 2 electrons. In the ground state , the only possible spin state is the singlet. So that means one of the electrons should be up and the other , down. If we excite one of the electrons to the next level , so in the first excited state of the system, one of the electrons will be in n=0, the other in n=1. So we can write the spatial part of the wave function either symmetrically or antisymmetric. If we write it as antisymmetric, then the spin part should be symmetric. For this, we have triplet state. But can we include the |1,1> and |1,-1> spin states? Because in the ground state , we concluded that the one of the electrons should be up and the other is down. So if it is the case, why should we include both up, and both down states for the first excited state of the system? Thank you.